# Java OutputStream printing speed

Tags: java, stringbuilder, outputstream

Suppose I had to print an array arr with comma-separated values. Right now, I am doing the following:

```
for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    System.out.print(arr[i] + ",");
}
```

However, for large arr lengths, I was wondering if this might be really slow. A second approach I had in mind was using StringBuilder, and constructing the final output string and only using 1 print statement. Would that be worth going for? The tradeoff would be more complicated code.

If it matters, I would like an answer for printing to console and printing to a file.

Comment: `System.out.print(String.join(", ", arr))`? Have you determined this is an important application bottleneck requiring optimization?

Comment: (1-) *However, for large arr lengths, I was wondering if this might be really slow.* - try it. *A second approach I had in mind was using StringBuilder,* - so now the tradeoff because having two copies of the data in memory. If you decide to use this approach the use a `StringJoiner`.

Comment: Unless you're going to be printing lines in the tens of thousands, I don't think that you'll notice any speed difference. And unless you've noticed a speed problem, why bother optimizing?

Comment: Right now, your generated CSV is slightly incorrect: you end up with a trailing comma after the last value. My point is: first get your code correct and readable. Then run it. And when you get to "oh, this is too slow", then worry about performance.

Comment: And yes: this isnt optimal: printing to stdout can cost in the order of milliseconds, whereas concat'ing strings in memory runs much faster. So, if you have 1 million values, there might be a noticeable difference between printing a million strings, or printing one really large string.

Comment: Printing to stdout can be slower than normal in some IDEs - I have noticed this in IntelliJ IDEA for as few as tens or hundreds of prints. Joining the string in memory first will be faster, but you will have to test for yourself to see if the difference is significant.

Comment: I am printing up to 10^7 values because I am writing algorithms with huge test cases. I am usually printing to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code isn't efficient because you have to instantiate a new String each time you calculate `arr[i] + ","`, which requires to allocate a new memory slot and discard the old string with the garbage collector when it's done.

The solution given by **Dave Newton** is the most efficient way to print your array. I've made a little benchmark with an array containing 20 000 elements (the biggest number I can choose in my small PC because displaying the array tends to distort the computing time when the array is too big):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] array = new String[20000];
        Arrays.fill(array, "A");

        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        /* Test 1 : using a for loop */
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            System.out.print(array[i] + ",");
    
        System.out.println();
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        /* Test 2 : using a for-each loop */
        for (String a : array)
            System.out.print(a + ",");
    
        System.out.println();
        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        /* Test 3 : using String.join */
        System.out.println(String.join(",", array));
        long t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    
        System.out.println("Test 1 : " + (t1 - t0) + "ms");
        System.out.println("Test 2 : " + (t2 - t1) + "ms");
        System.out.println("Test 3 : " + (t3 - t2) + "ms");
    }
}
```

I have the following results:

```
Test 1 : 110ms
Test 2 : 93ms
Test 3 : 0ms
```

[This website](https://www.journaldev.com/538/string-vs-stringbuffer-vs-stringbuilder#:%7E:text=String%20is%20immutable%20whereas%20StringBuffer,synchronized%20whereas%20StringBuilder%20is%20not.) explains the reason. `String.join` generates a `StringJoiner` instance which stores characters in a `StringBuilder`.

`StringBuilder` works as a buffer; appending `String`s in a buffer then display the result is way more efficient than instantiating the sum of 2 `String`s multiple times.